# Data collection loop help needed

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup, webdriver

I need the loop which will enter the product page, collect the data and then go to the next product and so forth.

And that loop should exist in the loop I already have (see below)

```
webdriver.ChromeOptions()
driver=webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='chromedriver', service_args=['--ssl-protocol=any', '--ignore-ssl-errors=true'])
driver.get("https://www.amazon.com/s?k=galaxy+s10&qid=1564815305&ref=sr_pg_2")

page = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html5lib')
# print(soup.prettify())
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 15)



page_links=[]
links=[]
name=[]
product_price=[]


var=0
while True:
    while True: #clicks on product and exists but the 1st product only!
        product=driver.find_element_by_class_name('s-search-results')
        time.sleep(2)
        product.find_element_by_class_name('a-text-normal').click()
        wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, "a-text-normal")))
        time.sleep(2)
        driver.execute_script("window.history.go(-1)")
#         driver.back() did not work
        continue

    driver.find_element_by_class_name('a-last').click()
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, "a-last")))
    var+=1
    if var == 3:
        driver.close()
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the post is not written in English.

Comment: @suspectus translated to English :)

Comment: Привет!
Если у тебя хромает разговорный английский, то рекомендую задать свой вопрос в русскоязычном секторе стэковерфлоу: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/
------
In this comment I recommend author to visit russian version of the stackoverflow.